# Appstore Submission refused for IPv6 not working

Tags: ipv6, appstore-approval, auth0

I have a hybrid mobile app built using Ionic and I am using Auth0 for authentication. My app is up and running in Google Play but finding issues to publish it to Apple Store. Reason behind that is Apple forces every app to use IPV6 and Auth0 gives error saying 'We could not reach the server. Please try again.'

What can be the possible causes for an App to be rejected to the app store when using Ionic / Auth0.

Comment: This might be an issue with Ionic or Cordova and IPv6, not IPv6 in general. Could you try setting up an IPv6 network as described in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html) (scroll down to "Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly").

Comment: I'll try that, Thanks Abhishred.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: I did set up my local wifi network as per the document link provided by Abhishrek and I did build again and could not reproduce issue after that

Comment: So you have just resubmitted the app and have passed review?

Comment: Pretty much  yes... But I tested first and code seemed to work...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)